# Virtual keyboard using UHID

Tags: c, linux, keyboard, hid

I am trying to achieve what the QMK firmware does for keyboards but using software. So, I would like to turn off keys, substitute some keys for others, layers and etc.

The first thing that appeared for me when searching was this example. The problem is, running the test it only works when the terminal that is executing the binary has focus, and I would like to overpass the windowing system.

Also the code presents this array that I don't have any idea how to fill.

```
static unsigned char rdesc[] = {
    0x05, 0x01, /* USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop) */
    0x09, 0x02, /* USAGE (Mouse) */
    0xa1, 0x01, /* COLLECTION (Application) */
    0x09, 0x01,     /* USAGE (Pointer) */
    0xa1, 0x00,     /* COLLECTION (Physical) */
    0x85, 0x01,         /* REPORT_ID (1) */
    0x05, 0x09,         /* USAGE_PAGE (Button) */
    0x19, 0x01,         /* USAGE_MINIMUM (Button 1) */
    0x29, 0x03,         /* USAGE_MAXIMUM (Button 3) */
    0x15, 0x00,         /* LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0) */
    0x25, 0x01,         /* LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1) */
    0x95, 0x03,         /* REPORT_COUNT (3) */
    0x75, 0x01,         /* REPORT_SIZE (1) */
    0x81, 0x02,         /* INPUT (Data,Var,Abs) */
    0x95, 0x01,         /* REPORT_COUNT (1) */
    0x75, 0x05,         /* REPORT_SIZE (5) */
    0x81, 0x01,         /* INPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs) */
    0x05, 0x01,         /* USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop) */
    0x09, 0x30,         /* USAGE (X) */
    0x09, 0x31,         /* USAGE (Y) */
    0x09, 0x38,         /* USAGE (WHEEL) */
    0x15, 0x81,         /* LOGICAL_MINIMUM (-127) */
    0x25, 0x7f,         /* LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (127) */
    0x75, 0x08,         /* REPORT_SIZE (8) */
    0x95, 0x03,         /* REPORT_COUNT (3) */
    0x81, 0x06,         /* INPUT (Data,Var,Rel) */
    0xc0,           /* END_COLLECTION */
    0xc0,       /* END_COLLECTION */
    0x05, 0x01, /* USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop) */
    0x09, 0x06, /* USAGE (Keyboard) */
    0xa1, 0x01, /* COLLECTION (Application) */
    0x85, 0x02,     /* REPORT_ID (2) */
    0x05, 0x08,     /* USAGE_PAGE (Led) */
    0x19, 0x01,     /* USAGE_MINIMUM (1) */
    0x29, 0x03,     /* USAGE_MAXIMUM (3) */
    0x15, 0x00,     /* LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0) */
    0x25, 0x01,     /* LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1) */
    0x95, 0x03,     /* REPORT_COUNT (3) */
    0x75, 0x01,     /* REPORT_SIZE (1) */
    0x91, 0x02,     /* Output (Data,Var,Abs) */
    0x95, 0x01,     /* REPORT_COUNT (1) */
    0x75, 0x05,     /* REPORT_SIZE (5) */
    0x91, 0x01,     /* Output (Cnst,Var,Abs) */
    0xc0,       /* END_COLLECTION */
};
```

I could not find any more documentation on the matter. At this time, I am not even sure if it is possible to do what I want. I have seen things like [KMonad](https://github.com/kmonad/kmonad) that I could not get to work.

At the end, these are my questions: 
How to fill the rdesc array to keyboards? 
How to overpass the windowing system? 
Where can I find documentation about UHID?